# How to get list of indices for elements whose value is the maximum in that list

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a list `l=[3,4,4,2,1,4,6]`
I would like to obtain a subset of this list containing the indices of elements whose value is max(l).
In this case, list of indices will be `[1,2,5]`.

I am using this approach to solve a problem where, a list of numbers are provided, for example

```
l=[1,2,3,4,3,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,2,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I need to identify the max occurence of an element, however in case more than 1 element appears the same number of times,
I need to choose the element which is greater in magnitude,
suppose I apply a counter on l and get `{1:5,2:5,3:4...}`, I have to choose '2' instead of '1'.
Please suggest how to solve this

Edit-
The problem begins like this, 
1) a list is provided as an input

```
l=[1 4 4 4 5 3]
```

2)I run a Counter on this to obtain the counts of each unique element

3)I need to obtain the key whose value is maximum

4)Suppose the Counter object contains multiple entries whose value is maximum,
as in `Counter{1:4,2:4,3:4,5:1}`
I have to choose 3 as the key whose value is 4.

5)So far, I have been able to get the Counter object, I have seperated key/value lists using `k=counter.keys();v=counter.values()`

6)I want to get the indices whose values are max in v
If I run v.index(max(v)), I get the first index whose value matches max value, but I want to obtain the list of indices whose value is max, so that I can obtain corresponding list of keys and obtain max key in that list.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please state your input and desired output more clearly.

Comment: Can you explain how you went from `l` to the `Counter` dict in 4?

Comment: @Giridhur I import Counter from collections, and send list as an argument to Counter. That returns a Counter object. As in 4, I have just used an example it may not relate to list specified in 1

Answer (score 0):

With long lists, using NumPy or any other linear algebra would be helpful, otherwise you can simply use either

`l.index(max(l))`

or

`max(range(len(l)),key=l)`

These however return only one of the many argmax's.

So for your problem, you can choose to reverse the array, since you want the maximum that appears later as :

`len(l)-l[::-1].index(max(l))-1`

Comment: n-l[::-1].index(max(l))-1 ;can you please explain this formula? What is n

Comment: so, first we find out the value of the maximum element, and we then reverse the list, and find out the location of the maximum element, and then get the index of the maximum element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the following should do what you want.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_largest_most_freq(lst):
    c = Counter(lst)
    # get the largest frequency
    freq = max(c.values())
    # get list of all the values that occur _max times
    items = [k for k, v in c.items() if v == freq]
    # return largest most frequent item
    return max(items)

def get_indexes_of_most_freq(lst):
    _max = get_largest_most_freq(lst)
    # get list of all indexes that have a value matching _max
    return [i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v == _max]

>>> lst = [3,4,4,2,1,4,6]
>>> get_largest_most_freq(lst)
4
>>> get_indexes_of_most_freq(lst)
[1, 2, 5]
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,3,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,4,3,2,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> get_largest_most_freq(lst)
3
>>> get_indexes_of_most_freq(lst)
[2, 4, 7, 14, 17, 19]
```

Comment: @AshwinV If this solved your question please feel free to accept it.